# Joomla backloggedin users issue (probably hacked)

Tags: administration, domain-hacks, joomla3

I made a Joomla! 3.1 site last month. Last 2 weeks I checked something weird, the backoffice panel shows me this:

[image]

The weird in this is that **I am the only person with access to administration panel.**
Is that possible some extension inject files via FTP or take free access to MySQL database? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It could be that your Admin sessions didn't expire.

Comment: Absolutely!!! My Session Lifetime was set to 9999999, just changed to 20, logout and login again and it looks great! Thanks @dan

Comment: No problem - glad it solved the issue for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [dan](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/28389/dan) suggested in the comments:

> It could be that your Admin sessions didn't expire.

Which did indeed cause the problem as [fiskolin](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/30961/fiskolin) indicated:

> Absolutely! My Session Lifetime was set to 9999999, just changed to 20, logout and login again and it looks great!